# При подключение меню в wordpress выходит ошибка?

Tags: php, wordpress

Решил подключить меню в Wordpress. Но выходит ошибка не пойму почему. Буду рад любой помощи.
Ошибки:

```
Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 'theme_register_nav_menu' not found or invalid function name in C:\Users\user\Desktop\OpenServer\domains\virtual\wp-includes\class-wp-hook.php on line 308

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at C:\Users\user\Desktop\OpenServer\domains\virtual\wp-includes\class-wp-hook.php:308) in C:\Users\user\Desktop\OpenServer\domains\virtual\wp-admin\includes\misc.php on line 1431





 //function.php



 add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'theme_register_nav_menu' );
    function virtual_register_nav_menu() {
    $locations= array(
        'header'=>__('header_menu','virtual_register'),
        'footer'=>__('footer_menu','virtual_register'),
    );
        register_nav_menus($locations);
        
    }
    add_action('init','virtual_register_nav_menu');
    ?>
```

Comment: Где функция `theme_register_nav_menu`?

Comment: Для начала: https://codex.wordpress.org/%D0%A7%D0%90%D0%92%D0%9E/Cannot_modify_header_information. И что за "function.php"? Файл темы должен называться function**s**.php

Comment: Всем спасибо. Файл у меня functions, просто описку сделал.   А с этой строкой ошибся- она лишняя)